# Transcoding multichannel audio to AAC failing

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I’m having issues transcoding multichannel audio to AAC.

Depending on the source material I either define a speaker layout/channel order and write that into the FMT chunk of an RF64 .wav (e.g. L R C) or leave the order undefined, with the intention of it being treated as multi-mono (channel: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.).

On conversion to AAC .m4a, FFMPEG either recognises there is a channel order and maps an equivalent from its standard list of [mappings](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) (sometimes a match, sometimes not), or fails conversion when the channels do not correlate to its own mappings - for example anything between 8 and 16 channels fail to transcode.

Is there a way to prevent FFMPEG applying its own channel-mapping when transcoding between formats?  Is there any way to transcode less common multichannel audio configurations (9 channels / 8.1) without it failing?

Command: `ffmpeg.exe -i example.wav -acodec aac example.mp4`

Comment: I guess you have to manually map the channels (there are plenty of examples on the page you are refering to).

Comment: The mappings don't allow for anything between 8-16 channels `octagonal` `hexadecagonal`, transcoding just fails as stated in the question

Comment: The only command you have copied in your question assumes an implicit mapping, and I am suggesting a manual explicit mapping. I can't see any command with explicit mapping in your question.